# Delta changes in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm wondering, when I press "deploy" in the google app engine launcher, how does it sync my changes to the actual instance.... maybe it would be better to ask specific questions :)

1) Does it only upload the delta changes (as opposed to the entire file) for changed files?

2) Does it only upload new files and changed files (i.e. does not copy pre-existing) unchanged files?

3) Does it delete remote files that do not exist locally?

4) Does all of this happen instantaneously for the end user once the app has finished deploying? (i.e. let's say I accidentally uploaded an insecure file that sits on example.com/passwords.txt - if #3 is true, then once I remove it from the local directory and re-deploy it should be gone- but can I be sure it is really gone and not cached on some edge somewhere?)

Comment: Have you tried [redownloading your code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Downloading_source_code) to see what it looks like up there?

Comment: I have not- though I know that the new code will be there- the question is more about how it is transferred. Also, it seems static files go through a different storage mechanism

Answer (score 3):

If you use only the launcher or the appcfg util as opposed to manage your code by means of git, AppEngine will keep only one 'state' of that particular version of your app and will not store any past state. So,

1) Yes, it uploads only deltas, not full files.

2) Yes, only new, modified or deleted files.

3) Yes, it deletes them if you delete locally and deploy. As Ibrahim Arief suggested, it is a good idea to [use appcfg](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Downloading_source_code) so you can prove it to yourself.

4) Here there are some caveats. With your new deploy, your old instances are sent a kill signal, and until it actually gets executed, there is a time span (seconds to minutes) during wich new requests could hit your previous version. 
It is also very important the point Port Pleco has made. You have to be careful with [caching on static files](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching). If you have a file with Expires or Cache-Control headers, and it is actually served, then it could be cached on various places so the existence of old copies of it, is completely out of your control.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a google employee so I don't have guaranteed accurate answers, but I can speak a little about your questions from my experience:

1) From what I've seen, it *does* upload all files each time

2) See 1, I'm fairly sure everything is uploaded

3) I'm not entirely sure whether it "deletes" the files, but I'm 99% sure that they're inaccessible if they don't exist in your current version. If you want to ensure that a file is inaccessible, then you can deploy your project with a new version number, and switch your app version to the new version in your admin panel. That will force google to use all your most recent files in that new version.

4) From what I've seen, changes that are rendered/executed, like html hardcoded text or controller changes or similar, appear instantly. Static files might be cached, as normal with web development, which means that you might have old versions of files saved on user's machines. You can use a query string on the end of the file name with the version to force an update on that.

For example, if I had a javascript file that I knew I would want to redeploy regularly, I would reference it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript src="../javascript/file.js?version=1.2" />
```

Then just increment the version number manually when I needed to force deployment of the javascript to my users.